# AngularJS - using data from a service in a directive

Tags: json, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-service

I have set up a service to collect JSONP data from a server. If I use console.log to output 'data.d.results' in the service, I get a simple array object with six items.

However, when I do the same thing within the directive I get a much more complex object returned - one containing $$state, error, success, proto at the top level.

Because this is a more complex object, I can't figure out how to refer to the actual data that I'm after.

Can anybody tell me where I'm going wrong when passing the data or what I need to do to reference the data in the directive? When I go down the tree in the developer tools I find the actual data here:

```
d > $$state > value > data > d > results > [0-5] > CardID
```

My code is below:

```
    app.directive('dashboardcard', ['DashboardCardService', function(DashboardCardService){
        return{
            restrict: 'E',
            link: function($scope, element, atttributes){
                $scope.data = DashboardCardService;
            },
            template: 'Card Name: {{CardID}}'
        };
    }]);    

    app.factory('DashboardCardService', ['$http', function($http){
        var request = {
            method: 'GET',
            url: '/api.svc/tbl_Card/',
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            useDefaultXhrHeader: false,
            headers: {'Content-type': 'application/json'},
            headers: {'Accept': 'application/json;odata=light;q=1,application/json;odata=verbose;q=0.5'},
            crossDomain: true
        };    

        return $http(request).success(function(data) {
            return data.d.results;
        });
    }]);
```

**Thank you**

Comment: `$http` returns a promise with some special methods, when you use `success` then the passed object would be data from response, but when you use `$http().then()` it will give you the more complicated object and server response will be in a `data` object

Comment: Thanks maurycy - I'm using `success` already - shouldn't this give the simple object if `then` provides the more complex one? I have tried with both and the directive is giving the same output for both.

Comment: yes, success should receive just the server response, BTW I see that you refer in `$http` request a path to your own server, do the call have to be jsonp?

Comment: No, the data comes from a WCF Entity Framework service - I chose JSONP as I thought this would be the most simple to use in Angular - what would be better? Do you know why `success` provides the 'simple' object when I use `console.log` in the service but a 'complex' object when I use `console.log` in the directive?

Comment: Ahhh I see now, you actually return `$http` promise from your factory not the data that is why you get different objects. I've made a plunker presenting different ways to pass data to directive, maybe it will be usefull for you http://plnkr.co/edit/YOzP2VCPOXwh4qoQC73i?p=preview and unless you do a real x-domain stuff it's better to use get or post

Comment: Thank you. I'm still absolutely completely lost but at least I understand why it is behaving differently in different parts of code. I wish there were a simple way to just get the data and put it on the page.

Answer (score 0):

One way to make it work with your current code and minimum changes would be something like that

```
app.directive('dashboardcard', ['DashboardCardService',   function(DashboardCardService){
    return{
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function($scope, element, atttributes){
            DashboardCardService.success(function(data){
              $scope.data = data
            });
        },
        template: 'Card Name: {{CardID}}'
    };
}]);    

app.factory('DashboardCardService', ['$http', function($http){
    var request = {
        method: 'GET',
        url: '/api.svc/tbl_Card/',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        useDefaultXhrHeader: false,
        headers: {'Content-type': 'application/json'},
        headers: {'Accept': 'application/json;odata=light;q=1,application/json;odata=verbose;q=0.5'},
        crossDomain: true
    };    

    return $http(request)
}]);
```

#### or

```
app.directive('dashboardcard', ['DashboardCardService', function(DashboardCardService){
    return{
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function($scope, element, atttributes){
            $scope.dashboardService = DashboardCardService;
        },
        template: 'Card Name: {{dashboardService.data.CardID}}'
    };
}]);    

app.factory('DashboardCardService', ['$http', function($http){
    var service = {};
    var request = {
        method: 'GET',
        url: '/api.svc/tbl_Card/',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        useDefaultXhrHeader: false,
        headers: {'Content-type': 'application/json'},
        headers: {'Accept': 'application/json;odata=light;q=1,application/json;odata=verbose;q=0.5'},
        crossDomain: true
    };    

    $http(request).success(function(data) {
       service.data = data.d.results;
    });
    return service
}]);
```

You can also check my plunk that demonstrates several ways to put data into directive from service

http://plnkr.co/edit/YOzP2VCPOXwh4qoQC73i?p=preview

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. That get's the 'simple' object into the directive. Now I just need to figure out how to get the actual data to show in the page - it's still coming through as blank on the first solution you provided. I think I must need to tell it which of the six objects I want to return? I'll eventually have this in an ng-repeat so I'm hoping that it will sort that out for me.